Unable to get frames from MIPI cameras on NVIDIA Jetson board in OpenCV/GStreamer
I have 4 mipi cameras connected to Jetson board. I can stream the cameras using GStreamer, buI want to use OpenCV for further processing. I tried several code but, I cant seem to get the stream from Nvargus in OpenCV, this is the code I've tried.
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
print(cv2.__version__)
dispW = 1200
dispH = 700
flip=2
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
dtav=0

camSet0='nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=0 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)500, height=(int)320, framerate=(fraction)30/1, format=(string)NV12 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, width=(int)500, height=(int)320 '
cam1 = cv2.VideoCapture(camSet0)

camSet1='nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=1 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)500, height=(int)320, framerate=(fraction)30/1, format=(string)NV12 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, width=(int)500, height=(int)320 '
cam2 = cv2.VideoCapture(camSet1)

camSet2='nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=2 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)500, height=(int)320, framerate=(fraction)30/1, format=(string)NV12 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, width=(int)500, height=(int)320 '
cam3 = cv2.VideoCapture(camSet2)

camSet3='nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=3 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)500, height=(int)320, framerate=(fraction)30/1, format=(string)NV12 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, width=(int)500, height=(int)320 '
cam4 = cv2.VideoCapture(camSet3)

startTime=time.time()

while True:
    ret, frame1 =cam1.read()
    ret, frame2 = cam2.read()
    ret, frame3 =cam3.read()
    ret, frame4 = cam4.read()
    # Ensure frames are not None before combining them
    if frame1 is None or frame2 is None or frame3 is None or frame4 is None:
        print("Error: One or more frames is None.")
        break

    framecombined = np.hstack((frame1, frame2, frame3, frame4))

    # Check if framecombined is not empty
    if framecombined.size == 0:
        print("Error: Combined frame is empty.")
        break

    cv2.imshow('Combo', framecombined)
    cv2.moveWindow('Combo', 0, 0)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cam1.release()
cam2.release()
cam3.release()
cam4.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

The error is always that the frames are empty, i also tried just one camera and get the same error:
File "panz1.py", line 33, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('Combo', frame1)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

Which means that its not getting any frames.
Please help.

you forgot the cam1.isOpened() checks. and the ret checks. -- and you assume that all those cameras produce frames in lockstep. generally not the case, unless use some kind of genlock or trigger all exposures simultaneously. since they're MIPI, there is a chance that they all get the same clock, but initializing them already introduces some relative delay, which may be visible. -- interesting file name. panz... er? panz... oom?

Hi, I tried the checks for cam1.isOpened, its always closed. The nvargus commands works when i use gstreamer, opencv for some reason doesnt seem to work with it.

any log lines appearing as you run this code? anything saying INFO or WARN? -- add an app sink to the pipeline.

Added appsink along with max-buffers=1 drop=true, no logs, videocapture doesnt give any error, isopened is always false for each camera, even when i connect only 1 camera and try.I also tried cam1 = cv2.VideoCapture(camSet0, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER) still nogo

Can you try to convert to BGR before feeding the appsink?

look for trivial pipeline descriptions that merely read from a known-good video file or generate synthetic video. as long as that doesn't work, there's no reason to suspect the hardware half of the operation. if it does, that would absolutely point to the hardware. either way, reduce/substitute until you've got video "working", then figure out how to make the video you want to show up

you know, opencv could be built against some gstreamer that is different from the gstreamer you used standalone. have a look at print(cv.getBuildInformation()). hopefully that'll tell you which gstreamer it's using.

Gstreamer support not available in OpenCV, i tried 20 different wats to install opencv from source to get gstreamer support in cmake, but it doesnt install with gstreamer at all, its so frustrating

Tried evrything from installing opencv from source multiple times with gstreamer and other settings ON, tried different scripts. Finally had to flash the OS a couple of times with some modification to make file to make it work.

Assuming that your camera provides 500x320@30, you may try:
import cv2
import re
print('GStreamer support: %s' % re.search(r'GStreamer\:\s+(.*)', cv2.getBuildInformation()).group(1))

camSet0 = 'nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=0 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=500, height=320, framerate=30/1, format=NV12 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx,width=500,height=320 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1'
cam1 = cv2.VideoCapture(camSet0, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
if not cam1.isOpened():
     print('Failed to open cam1')
     quit()

print('cam1 opened')
...


Gstreamer support not available in OpenCV, i tried 20 different wats to install opencv from source to get gstreamer support in cmake, but it doesnt install with gstreamer at all, its so frustrating

Try this script: https://github.com/AastaNV/JEP/blob/master/script/install_opencv4.6.0_Jetson.sh
